# magento 2.4.5-p2 to 2.4.6 composer update error

Tags: php, composer, magento2.4.6

magento 2.4.5-p2 to 2.4.6 composer update error

Problem 1
- symfony/config[v4.0.0, ..., v4.4.8] require php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.1.18) does not satisfy that requirement.
- Root composer.json requires [image: magento/product-community-edition 2.4.6] -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.6].
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/config v6.0.19 (conflict analysis result)
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/config v6.2.7 (conflict analysis result)
- Root composer.json requires pdepend/pdepend 2.5.2 -> satisfiable by pdepend/pdepend[2.5.2].
- pdepend/pdepend 2.5.2 requires symfony/config ^2.3.0|^3|^4 -> satisfiable by symfony/config[v2.3.0, ..., v2.8.52, v3.0.0, ..., v3.4.47, v4.0.0, ..., v4.4.44].
- You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: symfony/config[2.0.4, ..., v2.8.52, v3.0.0, ..., v3.4.47, v4.0.0, ..., v4.4.44, v5.0.0, ..., v5.4.21, v6.0.0, ..., v6.3.0].
- Conclusion: install one of symfony/config[v5.4.21, v6.0.19, v6.2.7] (conflict analysis result)

[image]

Comment: By the way its worked after  change "require-dev": {
"pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.2", to ==> "pdepend/pdepend": "^2.10",
}

Comment: can you add your composer.json file here? I will check and provide a solution for it.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow these steps

Step 1. Download latest `composer.json` by following command in **other temp** directory.

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition:2.4.6 .
```

Step 2. Take backup current `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files

Step 3. Upload the latest `composer.json` from temp directory to your project directory

Step 4. Run `composer update` command

Step 5. Run setup upgrade and deploy commands

Step 6. Now install other require modules

Comment: thanks , its working for new project but i am try to update existing project

Answer (score 0):

Please check these things will fix for you;

```
-> Composer Version 
-> PHP(FPM) Version
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try below steps for update existing project
First you need to check magento system requirements as per the version which link is given below and update first if required **Like :-** (php, composer, mysql, elastic search) version etc then start work on it.

You can upgrade magento version using command line follow below steps

1. First Enable maintenance mode using a command.
   **php bin/magento maintenance:enable**
2. Take backup of you composer.json file using command.
   **cp composer.json composer.json.bk**
3. Update composer.json file
   **composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.5-p1 --no-update**
4. Composer update
   **composer update**
5. Please run below commands one by one.
   **php bin/magento cache:clean**
   **rm -rf var/cache/***

   **rm -rf var/page_cache/***

   **rm -rf generated/code/***

   **php bin/magento setup:upgrade**

   **php bin/magento setup:di:compile**

   **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f**
6. Disable Maintainance Mode.
   **php bin/magento maintenance:disable**